# Corodva serve command just reset the app erasing all my changes

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

I use the command **cordova serve** to test the app in browser. But when I issue the command, I find all the code changes I made to the app has been disappeared include newly added js files etc. The app just got a complete reset. How can I avoid this and still use **cordova serve** command to test in browser? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue resolved.  It took sometime to figure out what is happening under the hood. As I was making changes directly in platform IOS directory, the cordova prepare or serve statement just replaces the code from the parent www folder.

To conclude, I have to make changes in root www folder and then issue the prepare/serve command that copies the code to the platform to test it out.